# Command Bar Menu Disappearing CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am facing an issue in CRM, the bug is when I create an appointment and try to save it, the commandBar go invisible after the load of the created record of the appointment. I try to inspect the javascript associated code but there is no hint about the source of the problem, I should say that after refreshing the page of the created page  the command bar become visible.

```
OnSave: function (e) {

    EOZ.Appointment.SetPivotalId();

    var eventArgs = e.getEventArgs();

    if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1 && eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 1 && !saveAndClose) {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon").addOnChange(EOZ.Appointment.CreatedOnChanged);
    }

    else {
        saveAndClose = true;
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("createdon").removeOnChange(EOZ.Appointment.CreatedOnChanged);
    }
},

CreatedOnChanged : function () {
    var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();      
    setTimeout(function () {
        Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("appointment", id);
    }, 500);

}
```

NB : After a lot of javascript debugging, i noticed that the problem is only happened when the method "CreatedOnChanged" is called more than once, in the  other hand if it's called just once the command bar is visible. I don't know if it's the source of the bug, but it is the only difference in the code's behaviour.

**Edit** :
Dynamics CRM 2013, Browser : Google chrome latest version on 03/03/2017
I modified my code to be like :

```
CreatedOnChanged : function () {
if(!isCalled){
    var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();      
    setTimeout(function () {
        Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("appointment", id);
    }, 500);
    isCalled = true;
    }
}
```

The method "CreatedOnChanged" is called multible times but its content is executed just once, and the command bar is displayed correctly ... But really i don't why when this method is executed multiple times, the command bar become hidden.

Comment: Dynamics CRM version? Browser version? What happens when you disable all custom scripts on the form? B.t.w. the code in the `else` block gets execute on update-form and when save mode != 1. Is this what you intended?

Comment: To @HenkvanBoeijen, I edited my question, The else code is executed when i press on 'Save & close' button, and if I disable all custom scripts the command bar is displayed correctly after the creation of the appointment activity

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  I think is quite unusually to see an onchanged handler registered against the CreatedOn field.

Comment: To @Malachy I added The onchanged Event to resolve a microsoft's bug, it serve only to reload the created entity

Comment: Can you provide some more insight on the Microsoft bug you are trying to address?

Answer (score 0):

It look to me like you are trying to refresh the page after a save.

Rather than trying to reopen the form I think that forcing a refresh may be more correct:

```
Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true);
```

I think that you code around registering the event on the OnCreate() event is probably causing an error.  The ribbon automatically refreshes after a save (so any visibility / enabling conditions or javascript can be retested.

A JavaScript error on the page would potentially cause the JavaScript re-rendering the ribbon to fail.